# String as Indexer in C#

Tags: c#, string, indexer

Let me start by showing the code:

```
public class Collection
{
    private object[] values;

    public Collection(int size) => values = new object[size];

    public object this[string index] 
    { 
        get => values[index]; 
        set => values[index] = (object)value;
    }
} 
public class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        Collection collection = new Collection(3);
        collection["integer"] = 123;
        collection["decimal"] = 456.78;
        collection["text"]    = "Hello World!";

        double total = (double)(int)collection["integer"] + (double)collection["decimal"];
        Console.WriteLine("Total is {0}", total);

        Console.WriteLine();

        Collection collection2 = new Collection(2);
        collection2["integer"] = 123;
        collection2["decimal"] = 456.78;
        collection2["text"]    = "Hello World!"; // This wont be added because of limit
    }
}
```

I'm doing this tutorial, and class `Program` was already given to me, and I can't modify it. What I need to do is to create `Collection` class, so `Collection` class is made by me. But there is this problem with `Indexer`, because it is `string` it doesn't seem to work the same way integer Indexers worked in previous tutorials. Is there a way to use string as Indexer, or should I consider different approach? Also adding namespaces are not allowed. I have been stuck in this tutorial for a week now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Dictionary collection:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
dict["hello"] = "world";
```

Comment: doesnt dictionary require adding namespace?

Comment: @RohitMalish yes, so it would fail your learning exercise. However, if you where going to do this the "normal" way without the constrains a Dictionary would be the correct answer to use.

Comment: You just can write using statement: using System.Collections.Generic; above namespace section. Or write namespace explicitly: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object> dict;

Comment: You (and the people upvoting this) are not understanding the comment "*adding namespaces are not allowed.*". This tutorial is to teach him to create his own string indexer, yes in a normal environment Dictionary would be the correct way to do it, but it is the wrong answer to "how to teach someone how to write their own string indexer"

Comment: No additional references are allowed.

Comment: Actually I found out that I am allowed to use it in this form: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary. And because you were first to answer I'm accepting your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As a hint to point you in the right direction, (you are learning so I don't want to give it away> have Collection store two arrays, a `object[]` and `string[]`. See if that gets you going on the right direction.

If you need a further hint follow [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eha9t187.aspx).

> You will need to store the string name in the `string[]` in the same index you store the object in the `object[]`. Then if you call `var intIndex = Array.IndexOf(stringCollection, index)` you can use the result of that as `return values[intIndex]`;

**See if you can figure it out without following the link, or looking at the spoiler text above first!**

Comment: This is appropriate as a comment, but not as an answer.

Comment: @Servy I give a full solution, I don't want to just tell him the answer but by following the MSDN link and the instructions I give it is a complete answer.

Comment: An answer on SO needs to be self contained.  It should answer the question without requiring the reader to follow any links.  That's not to say that I think you should do this person's work for them, merely that, since you aren't, you shouldn't be posting it as an answer.

Comment: @Servy There you go, I and to go to `meta` to figure out how to add spoiler text.

Answer (score 1):

Without using Dictionary...

This stores an object array and string array. The string array is used as your indexer, and the object array as your values. The keys and values are stored at the same location in their respective arrays.

There is plenty of optimization and improvement to be had here... but it should be a starting point.

```
class Collection
{
    int size;
    int items;
    string[] keys;
    object[] values;

    public Collection(int size)
    {
        keys = new string[size];
        values = new object[size];
        this.size = size;
        items = 0;
    }

    public object this[string index]
    {
        get
        {
            int position = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++)
                if (keys[i] == index)
                    position = i;

            if (position == -1)
                throw new ArgumentException("Index Not Found");

            return values[position];                
        }
        set
        {
            int position = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                if (keys[i] != null && keys[i] == index)
                    position = i;

            if (position != -1)
            {
                values[position] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                if (items == size)
                    throw new Exception("Collection full");

                keys[items] = index;
                values[items] = value;
                items++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach, just a little different from the one you mentioned but working perfectly.

```
using System;

namespace ass5
{
    class Session
    {

        string[] values;
        string[] key;
        int i=0;

        public Session(int size)
        {
            values = new string[size];
            key=new string[size];
        }

        public string this[string index]
        {
            get
            {
                
               // i++;
                int intIndex = Array.IndexOf(key, index);

                if(intIndex==-1)
               {
                   return " error";
               }
                
                return values[intIndex];
            }
            set
            {
               key[i]=index; // for index string storage
               i++;
               int intIndex= Array.IndexOf(key, index);
               
               values[intIndex] = value; // for value corresponding to that index
            }
        }
    } 

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Session session=new Session(5);
            session["username"]="user";
            session["password"]="password"; 
            Console.WriteLine(session["username"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the index is already present: the set will unnnecessarily consume one additional array element. Also, you do not check whethere there is still room for another element.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your class as below. check for ContainsKey is a good practice

```
class Collection
{

    Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public object this[string index]
    {
        get
        {
            if(values.ContainsKey(index)
            {
              return values[index];
            }
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            if(!values.ContainsKey(index)
            {
              values.Add(index, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP states that he cannot use references to other libraries, such as System.Collections.